# Counting the number of hits for a given search query/term per document in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table containing blobs of document text that I am joining to. Using oracle text, i can get the snippet of text containing my search term (using ctx_doc.snippet). However, I must now specify the number of times this search term was found for each document that matched my join not all documents that i have. I have over 100K documents total but joins i do and filtering return a subset.

Reading online, there's CTX_QUERY.COUNT_HITS that i can use but that gives the count for all documents. If I had a textkey paraemeter for COUNT_HITS, life would be good but none exists.

How can i go about accomplishing the number of hits for a given query in a document in Oracle?

Comment: Can you give some code?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/text.121/e17747/cdocpkg.htm#CCREF2123

Comment: `SELECT CTX_DOC.SNIPPET('COSI.DOC_BLOB_CONTENT_IDX', 625660, 'NOTIFICATION LETTER')  
                              FROM DUAL;
`

Comment: The code above is currently how i get a document snippet from the database for a given search term. I attempted using the CTX_DOC.HIGHLIGHT procedure but it would require me going through each document and doing a count of the hits which frankly is computationally expensive. [link](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCREF/cdocpkg.htm#i997035)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue using CTX_DOC; the procedure [HIGHLIGHT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24436/cdocpkg.htm#CCREF0706) can be contorted slightly to do exactly what you're asking for.

Using this environment:

```
create table docs ( id number, text clob, primary key (id) );

Table created.

insert all
 into docs values (1, to_clob('a dog and a dog'))
 into docs values (2, to_clob('a dog and a cat'))
 into docs values (3, to_clob('just a cat'))
select * from dual;

3 rows created.

create index i_text_docs on docs(text) indextype is ctxsys.context;

Index created.
```

`CTX_DOC.HIGHLIGHT` has an OUT parameter of a HIGHLIGHT_TAB type, which contains the count of the number of hits within a document.

```
declare
   l_highlight ctx_doc.highlight_tab;
begin
  ctx_doc.set_key_type('PRIMARY_KEY');

  for i in ( select * from docs where contains(text, 'dog') > 0 ) loop
     ctx_doc.highlight('I_TEXT_DOCS', i.id, 'dog', l_highlight);
     dbms_output.put_line('id: ' || i.id || ' hits: ' || l_highlight.count);
  end loop;

end;
/
id: 1 hits: 2
id: 2 hits: 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Obviously if you're doing this in a query then a procedure isn't the best thing in the world, but you can wrap it in a function if you want:

```
create or replace function docs_count (
        Pid in docs.id%type, Ptext in varchar2
         ) return integer is

   l_highlight ctx_doc.highlight_tab;
begin
  ctx_doc.set_key_type('PRIMARY_KEY');
  ctx_doc.highlight('I_TEXT_DOCS', Pid, Ptext, l_highlight);
  return l_highlight.count;
end;
```

This can then be called normally

```
select id
     , to_char(text) as text
     , docs_count(id, 'dog') as dogs
     , docs_count(id, 'cat') as cats
  from docs;

        ID TEXT                  DOGS       CATS
---------- --------------- ---------- ----------
         1 a dog and a dog          2          0
         2 a dog and a cat          1          1
         3 just a cat               0          1
```

If possible, it might be simpler to replace the keywords as Gordon notes. I'd use [`DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21645/d_lob.htm#TTPLP66709) function instead of simply `LENGTH()` to avoid potential problems, but [`REPLACE()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm) works on CLOBs so this won't be a problem. Something like the following (assuming we're still searching for dogs)

```
select (dbms_lob.getlength(text) - dbms_lob.getlength(replace(text, 'dog')))
         / length('dog')
  from docs
```

It's worth noting that string searching gets progressively slower as strings get larger (hence the need for text indexing) so while this performs fine on the tiny example given it might suffer from performance problems on larger documents.

---

I've just seen [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24660075/counting-the-number-of-hits-for-a-given-search-query-term-per-document-in-oracle/25095318#comment39029248_24660075):

> ... but it would require me going through each document and doing a count of the hits which frankly is computationally expensive

No matter what you do you're going to have to go through each document. You want to find the exact number of instances of a string within another string and the *only* way to do this is to look through the entire string. (I would highly recommend reading [Joel's post on strings](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html); it makes a point about XML and relational databases but I think it fits nicely here too.) If you were looking for an estimate you could calculate the number of times a word appears in the first 100 characters and then average it out over the length of the LOB (crap algorithm I know), but you want to be accurate.

Obviously we don't know how Oracle has implemented all their functions internally, but let's make some assumptions. To calculate the length of a string you need to literally count the number of bytes in it. This means iterating over the entire string. [There are some algorithms to improve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584340/how-to-write-a-better-strlen-function), but they still involve iterating over the string. If you want to replace a string with another string, you have to iterate over the original string, looking for the string you want to replace.

Theoretically, depending on how Oracle's implemented everything, using `CTX_DOC.HIGHLIGHT` should be quicker than anything else as it only has to iterate over the original string once, looking for the string you want to find and storing the byte/character offset from the start of the original string.

The suggestion `length(replace(<original string>, <new string>)) - length(<original string)` may have to iterate three separate times over the original string (or something that's close to it in length). I doubt that it would actually do this as everything can be cached and Oracle should be storing the byte length to make `LENGTH()` efficient. This is the reason I suggest using `DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH` rather than just `LENGTH()`; Oracle's almost certainly storing the byte length of the document.

If you don't want to parse the document each time you run your queries it might be worth doing a single run when loading/updating data and store, separately, the words and the number of occurrences per document.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Doing an offline approach might be ideal but i was hoping Oracle implemented something that would work hand in hand with their document snippet call. That way, you can get in one shot the number of search terms in the text when the snippets are returned.

Comment: I am trying to really avoid another such call that takes time when users are using the application. For now, i have been able to get the requirements eliminated due to performance concerns

Comment: You could write something to get everything when you're getting the snippet; but I suspect that would slow the snippet search down as that can stop iterating through the document as soon as it's found what it's looking for. If search terms aren't known in advance and you're unable to make a full search quick enough have you considered doing it asynchronously in your application instead?

Comment: sorry for the late response. Yea, that would slow down the snippet search. If by the application, you mean asynchronously looking for the search term in the results or a call to the database to do it? I have a time that I have to adhere to; searches mustn't take any longer than 5 mins. Excluding the hitcount now, i am almost at a minute per search because i also have to search sharepoint document libraries (they are huge) . So anything that will be a performance cost, i am trying to eliminate

Answer (score 0):

If by "blobs of document text" you mean "clob", then you can use this tried true method.  Take the difference between length of the document and the length of the document with the search string replaced by something else.  That will give you the number of matches.

For example:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             length(replace(t.doc, KEYWORD, KEYWORD || 'x')) - length(t.doc) as nummatches
      from table t
     ) t
order by nummatches desc;
```

Answer (score -1):

Sure you can handle that on pl/sql directly(explain will help you with that), but quick and dirty, create a view dynamically (one that filter to your subset) and execute count_hits.

Comment: can you explain further. How would that work with document snippet in oracle. I need to count the number of time a given search term or its variation exists in a document. The document can be anything from 1 page to 1000 pages, and this count algorithm needs to be super fast