# Count length of string in C without using string.h library (using char pointers)

Tags: c, pointers

I need to count the length of a string in C without using the string.h library, using char pointers. So far all the methods I've seen use the string.h library. Is it possible to do it without i?

Comment: Well, yes, `strlen` from `string.h` has to do it without other libraries. See also the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) that shows a possible implementation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a better strlen function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584340/how-to-write-a-better-strlen-function)

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible, the end of a string in C is usually null terminated, so you can loop through the string until you find the '\0' character, counting each as you go.

Answer (score 3):

When talking about strings in C, you're essentially talking about an array of `char`, terminated by the nil character (`'\0'`). The length of a string, therefore is:

```
size_t len(const char *s) {
    // if no string was passed (null pointer), just return
    if (s == NULL)
        return 0;

    size_t ln;
    // iterate over string until you encounter the terminating char
    for (ln=0;s[ln] != '\0'; ln++);

    return ln;
}
```

As pointed out by @chux-ReinstateMonica: the correct type to return here is `size_t`, if you want to avoid potential overflow issues + you're looking for a drop-in replacement for the `strlen()` function in `strings.h`. The length of a string can, after all, never be negative, so using the unsigned `size_t` makes more sense than the signed `int`.

Now this obviously assumes the input was a valid string. If I were to do something like:

```
int main( void ) {
    char * random = malloc(1024); // allocate 1k chars, without initialising memory
    printf("length is: %zu\n", len(random)); // use %zu because size_t is unsigned!
    return 0;
}
```

There's no guarantee the memory I allocated will even contain a terminating character, and therefore it's not impossible for the function to return a value greater than 1024. Same goes for something like:

```
char foo[3] = {'f', 'o', 'o'}; // full array, no terminating char
```

This string, in memory, could look something like this:

```
//the string - random memory after the array
| f | o | o | g | a | r | b | a | g | e | U | B | \0 |
```

Making it look like a string of 12 characters. If you then use the assumed length of 12 to write past the actual array, all bets are off (undefined behaviour).

This string should've been:

```
char foo[4] = {'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'}; // or char[4] foo = "foo";
```

You can read an old answer I gave elsewhere for some more details on how to get the length of a string passed to a function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022644/how-to-get-the-real-and-total-length-of-char-char-array/21022815#21022815)

Comment: Fails when string length exceeds `int` range.  This `len()` does not match the return type of `strlen()`.  Code like `printf("length is: %d\n", len(random));` needs more maintenance when switching between `len()` and `strlen()` to also adjust the print specifier.  These issues solvable with using `size_t` than `int`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: You're right, I believe I actually mention using `size_t` in the answer I linked at the bottom. Will update the code here, though

Answer (score 1):

Here example:

```
size_t pos(char* s)
{
    size_t lenS; //len of string

    for (lenS = 0; s[lenS]; lenS++);

    return lenS;
}
```

Comment: Fails when string length exceeds `int` range.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Doubt it matters. It's probably homework, and if it's not, it's just gotta be something embedded enough where a string exceeding int range is unreasonable.

Comment: When `int` and `size_t` differ in size, printing the result of `len()` and `strlen()` then  require different print specifiers even when the string length is 1.  When coding for a strlen() replacement, makes most sense to use the same function signature. `size_t strlen(const char *s);` rather than change the type of the argument and return.